# Xcode: Can't build OpenGL project with SOIL

Tags: xcode, soil

I try to run SOIL under Xcode in a C++ project with OpenGL. When I add the files to my project it automatically adds "libSOIL.a" to target's "Link Binary With Libraries". I added in my main.cpp:

```
#include "lib/soil/src/SOIL.h"
```

When I build the project, I always get the error

> /.../Projects/XCode/OpenGLTest/OpenGLTest/lib/soil/src/test_SOIL.cpp:4:10: 'windows.h' file not found

I don't know why SOIL tries to compile something with the 'widows.h' because I'm under OS X. I searched the web but I find no solution. I hope somebody can help me here and explain if I can run SOIL easily.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I posted the question also on another board and finally got a an answer [Xcode: Can't build OpenGL project with SOIL](http://www.tutorial-portal.com/board/thread/id/5)

Now it works!

Comment: FYI the URL in this answer currently goes to a site that hijacks Safari with a malicious script.